# Angularjs data compare

Tags: angularjs, validation, datetime, datepicker

I'm new in 'JavaScript AngularJS'. I'm writing because I need to know how to compare if data in my `date-time picker` is `>` of 40 year from today and if is not then I need to see an error.

Comment: Hi, please try to rephrase your question, as its is quite broad and poorly worded. As a hint: you can use validators and ngMessages for it.

Comment: OK . and sorry for my bad English..I need to validate a date field value if is > of 40 years ago then if is it I don't see any message but if it isn't the I need to see an error message in page..

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless your question is about this plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's documentation provides a nice example for it:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

I've edited it to better suit your needs:
http://plnkr.co/edit/B8jATONx6yBMwWPAXspc?p=preview

```
<input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
   placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="1976-03-08"/>

{{myForm.input.$error}}

<div role="alert">
 <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.min">
     Smaller than minimum!</span>
</div>
```

You basically need to add the `min` directive to an input. Once the input has an error, `myForm.input.$error` will contain all erroneous validators.

Comment: Is possible to use mindate as calculate date.. For example today -40 years go??